# create function that behaves like continuedFraction

Tags: functions

I'm just starting to learn *Mathematica* and I got stuck at this question. This a noob question but please help.

I need to define a function named continuedFraction that takes user input of type list as this `continuedFraction[{a,b,c,d}]` that will output

```
a / (1 + b/ (1 + c/ (1 + d)))
```

this is just any other continued fraction like on this page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ContinuedFraction.html

what I had done so far after 383 inputs in notebook (now you know how hard this is for me)

```
fx[x_] := Fold[x/(1 + #) &, x, {a, b, c,}]

fx[{a, b, c, e}]

 {a/(1 + a/(1 + a/(1 + a/(1 + a)))), 
  b/(1 + b/(1 + b/(1 + b/(1 + b)))), 
  c/(1 + c/(1 + c/(1 + c/(1 + c)))), 
  e/(1 + e/(1 + e/(1 + e/(1 + e))))}
```

which is of course, not the correct answer. 
ps: this is under functional programming-> pure function and a hint to use Fold.

Comment: Why not use [`FromContinuedFraction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FromContinuedFraction.html)?

Comment: because I am asked to create a function of my own definition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting close.  (`Fold` is an excellent choice.)  Try:

```
f[x_List] := Fold[#2/(1 + #) &, 0, Reverse@x]

f[{a, b, c, d}]
```

> ```
> a/(1 + b/(1 + c/(1 + d)))
> ```

Comment: Suggested reading: [(1)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121), [(2)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users)

Comment: thank you very much. how can I didn't see the #2 before! pheww~