# Iterating `Log` infinitely

Tags: iterators

How is it possible to find the limiting value of `Log[x Log[x Log[x Log[...]]]]` in *Mathematica*? Apparently, it should give `-ProductLog[-1,-1/x]`, but I can't seem to replicate that ...

Comment: If u==Log[x Log[x ...]] then u==Log[x u] and FullSimplify[ Reduce[u==Log[x u],u]] will show you the range of possibilities depending on all the values that x might have.

Comment: Related: [(66085)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66085/121)

Comment: Letting `y=Log[x*Log[x*...]]` gives `Exp[y]=x*Log[x*...]=x*y`. Now solve for `y`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `FixedPoint`:

```
FixedPoint[Log[3.5 #] &, 3.5] == -ProductLog[-1, -1/3.5]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

In general, if $y = f(f(...f(f(...))))$, then $y = f(y)$. Solving for $y$ will give us the formula for the infinitely nested expression.

In your case, `f == Log[x #]&`, which gives

```
sol = Refine[Reduce[y == Log[x y], y], x > 0]
```

[image]

Unfortunately `FullSimplify` can't prove `Im[ProductLog[-1, -(1/x)]] >= -π` for `x > 0`. We can extract the possible solutions for `y` manually:

```
Or @@ Cases[sol, y == f_ :> y == FullSimplify[f], Infinity]
```

> ```
> y == -ProductLog[-1, -1/x] || y == -ProductLog[-1/x] || y == -ProductLog[1, -1/x]
> ```

Comment: great solution - thank you!  :)