# Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable

Tags: syntax, files-and-directories, output

I'm new to *Mathematica*, so I suspect this question involves either a misunderstanding involving variables or the usage of `>>>`.

On a *webMathematica* page (backed by *Mathematica* 5.2), I have the following:

```
foo[arg_] := Module[{argN},
    ArgN = arg;
    filenameS ="Absolute/Path/To/File";
    ArgN >>> filenameS; (*Problem Line*)
];
foo["test"];
```

Running this appears to do nothing. When I replace the line

```
ArgN >>> filenameS;
```

with

```
PutAppend[ArgN, filenameS];
```

It works perfectly, appending `"test"` to the file. Why doesn't the infix form of `PutAppend` work in the same way?

Comment: Also, `ArgN >> "Absolute/Path/To/File"` works. Puzzling.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe it *does* work, just not how you expect. :-)

From the documentation for [`PutAppend`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PutAppend.html):

[image]

Note that there are *no quotation marks* around `filename` in the first line.
It is not made particularly clear but you can use this syntax with `>>>`:

```
Range[10] >>> file.txt
```

Which outputs to a file named `file.txt` directly.  This is a special and unusual parsing, used also for `>>` (`Put`) and `<<` (`Get`).

Because of this **your results are being sent to a file named `filenameS`** rather than one named according to the string value of `filenameS`.

Usually `file.txt` would be interpreted as `Dot[file, txt]`, but in the case of `>>>` it is parsed differently.  Here is a low-level look at what is going on.  `parseString`<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/121)</sup> parses as string using the Front End into Box form.

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]

"data >>> file.txt" // parseString
"data :> file.txt"  // parseString
```

> ```
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"data", ">>>", "file.txt"}]], StandardForm}
>
> {BoxData[RowBox[{"data", ":>", RowBox[{"file", ".", "txt"}]}]], StandardForm}
> ```

Note the different handling. Here RuleDelayed was used as an arbitrary "normal" operator.

---

As further illustration of the special parsing we can demonstrate that neither `Function` nor `With` can effect the substitution.  This outputs to a file named `x` rather than `myfile.txt`:

```
With[{x = "myfile.txt"},
 Range[5] >>> x
]
```

This isn't even valid input:

```
(Range[5] >>> #) &["myfile.txt"]
```

> Syntax::sntxf: "(" cannot be followed by "Range[5]>>>#)".
>
> Syntax::tsntxi: "Range[5]>>>#" is incomplete; more input is needed.

Nevertheless we can attempt to override the behavior with `$PreRead` or `MakeExpression` which work at the Box level:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{lhs_, ">>>", rhs_String}], form_] :=
  MakeExpression[
    RowBox[{"PutAppend", "[", RowBox[{lhs, ",", rhs}], "]"}],
    form
  ] /; ! StringMatchQ[rhs, "\"*\""]
```

Now any appearance of `lhs >>> rhs` where `rhs` is not a string should behave as `PutAppend[lhs, rhs]`, assuming I wrote the rule correctly.

Comment: You can use pathnames if the 'filename' is in quotes: `Range[100] >>> "/tmp/wizard.txt"`... So there's no way to pass a file or pathname into this `>>>` syntax?

Comment: @cormullion (1) Yes.  (2) That's correct AFAIK.

Comment: Well that's a little annoying... Thanks though. I'll mark as answer in a couple hours (assuming nothing else shows up).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Under the documentation for Put, it states that `expr >> filename is equivalent to expr >> "filename"`, and PutAppend is supposed to work the same as Put. Is this just misleading documentation?

Comment: @Daniel Actually I think that describes the behavior rather well: the point is you can omit the quotation marks and it behaves the same way.  Since this behavior displeases you I'll see if I can provide a practical work-around.

Comment: @Daniel please see the extension to my answer; if you find any cases where it does not work let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Answer (score 8):

Mr. Wizard's answer is basically correct.  I was originally going to just edit his answer, but I decided this is a bit too much to do that.  Mr. Wizard, feel free to delete my answer and just incorporate this info into yours.

There are six special "auto-stringifying" operators, namely:

```
 >> >>> << :: ? ??
```

These parse the argument to their right.  If the argument is a string, they they will slurp up that whole string.  If the argument isn't a string, they will read until they've reached the end of a file name (as defined in [Operator Input Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html#26140)) for the first three or a symbol for the last 3.  This argument is then converted to a string before any evaluation happens.  Indeed,

```
In[38]:= Hold[<< foo] // InputForm
Out[38]//InputForm= Hold[Get["foo"]]
```

and

```
In[43]:= foo::bar::English//FullForm
Out[43]//FullForm= MessageName[foo,"bar","English"]
```

Because this happens deep in the parser (converter of boxes or text to Wolfram Language expressions) before any evaluation happens, there really is no way to change this short of something like the `MakeExpression` rule proposed by Mr. Wizard.  Of course, then something like `a >>> myfile.txt` will no longer work after that change.

You call always used the `head[args]` form if you want to use any arbitrary expression.  Incidentally, both `?` and `??` are different forms of `Information`.

Comment: Also, there's the weird operators `_` `__` `___` which, in the front-end, "stringify" stuff directly to the left *and* right of them, but internally gets parsed into a `Pattern[Symbol, Blank[Symbol]]`.

Comment: At the risk of being overly pedantic, the underscores are not operators, nor do they stringify any more then Sin stringfiies (if you look at the boxes for `Sin[x]`, you'll see it involves `"Sin"` and several other strings).  What's happening is that they *tokenize* together with symbol tokens on either side.  Then they parse according to the special rules of tokens which have underscores in them, just as if you evaluated `ToExpression["f_h"]`.  Notice in the above tutorial they are listed in the "special input form" table, not the "operator precedence" table.