# Using a variable in Get

Tags: files-and-directories

This question is different from the answer here [Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/infix-form-of-putappend-does-not-work-with-variable) becasue it is dealing with folders and not filenames.

I have a file path which I save to a varible using the `FileNameSetter`. I then use the `StringJoin` to add the last folder name to this path. When I do this with a notebook file and then use `NotebookEvaluate` for example, *Mathematica* understands that this variable is a file location and executes without a problem. However when I do the same thing for a package and use the `Get (or <<)` *Mathematica* doesn't seem to understand that the variable is a location.

Setting up the file location

```
FileNameSetter[Dynamic[DashboardFile]];
DashboardFile
SetDirectory[DirectoryName[DashboardFile]]
PackageLocation = DirectoryName[DashboardFile] <> "Packages"


"\\\\ecsdbn-srv-02\\lara_jordan$\\Cleaner Kumba\\my redev\\tabview \
v1.6.nb" 
"\\\\ecsdbn-srv-02\\lara_jordan$\\Cleaner Kumba\\my redev"
"\\\\ecsdbn-srv-02\\lara_jordan$\\Cleaner Kumba\\my redev\\Packages"
```

Setting up the package location

```
PackageA = PackageLocation <> "\\HA1Package.m"
<< PackageA
<< "\\\\ecsdbn-srv-02\\lara_jordan$\\Cleaner Kumba\\my redev\\Packages\\HA1Package.m"

"\\\\ecsdbn-srv-02\\lara_jordan$\\Cleaner Kumba\\my redev\\Packages\\HA1Package.m"
Get::noopen: Cannot open PackageA. >>
$Failed
```

In the third line in the code above I have simply copied and pasted the value of `PackageA` just to the right on the `<<` so I know that the location stored in the variable `PackageA` is valid.

I need this to work becasue I have hundreds of packages where each new user will just be asked to enter one file location that will automatically be used for all packages.

Comment: I have marked this question as a duplicate because the cause is already explained for `Put`.  Your question will not be deleted, and will serve as a signpost for others to find the original question. +1  (In brief: use `Get[PackageA]`)

Comment: Thanks, that works. Can you explain though why it works? The other answer which you directed me to I don't understand at all.

Comment: Since that other answer is my own I'm afraid I may not be able to explain it better.  Put simply, *Mathematica* treats `<<` (and `>>` and `>>>`) in a highly unusual way: anything to the right of these operators is recognized as a String, even *without* the `" "` marks.  Therefore your code is trying to read in a file with a literal name of `PackageA`.

Comment: Oh ok thanks, that is the short and sweet answer which I do understand. Thanks so much.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: I notice that you added a header to this question referencing the one I closed it as a duplicate of.  I'm not sure how to interpret that.  Do you feel this question should not have been closed?