# Why is FileNameJoin not working?

Tags: files-and-directories

I can not figure out why the code below doesn't work?

```
aaa >> FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]
```

error message came out saying

> OpenWrite::noopen: Cannot open FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}].

If I evaluate

```
FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]
```

directly, then I can get

```
C:\Users\m&p\AppData\Local\Temp\input
```

And the code below always works

```
aaa >> "C:\\Users\\m&p\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\input"
```

Comment: did you type this in a notebook? what is `aaa >>` ? Did you check to see if you have a file called ` FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]` ? i.e. evaluate ` FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]` and see what it says, then go see if that file exist. btw, you code says "input" but the message you show says "input2"

Comment: @Nasser I've edited my question. aaa can be anything just for convenience. If I didn't define aaa, the aaa>>file will put 3 "a" characters into file .

Comment: @Nasser and it shouldn't be a matter if there is already a file with the name "input" exit? `Put` always write, I think

Comment: It works fine for me, `"test" >> FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "input"}]` no errors, and the file is created fine as `C:\Users\me\Documents\input` and I opened the file with text editor and it has "test" in it. Windows 7, M V 9.01. It might be the space you have there in the folder path? what is that `&` you show there in the name?

Comment: @Nasser That is strange! It's not only happened in my local mathematica, it also happens why I use mathematica on HPC, sometimes it did't create a file, sometimes it creates a file named "FileNameJoin[.....]"? That makes crazy

Comment: try `Get["input", Path -> Directory[]]` and see what you get. I get the file name I created ok.

Comment: This question is almost a duplicate of "[Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30489/280)" and a duplicate of "[Using a variable in Get](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31636/280)."

Answer (score 5):

Mathematica 9.0, WinXP

Apparently both forms of `Put[]` (ie `Put[]` and `>>`) don't operate with the same criteria on the file name treatment. Please take a look at the syntax coloring in the following example:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

While the standard `Put[]` waits for an expression to be interpreted, the `>>` form waits for a String (with or without apostrophes).

So, when you enter

```
aaa >> FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]
```

it tries to write to a file whose name is *literally*  "FileNameJoi ..." etc. and fails.

It can be circumvented by entering

```
aaa >> (FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "input"}])
```

--
Very curious, BTW.

Comment: I would call it "a bug by design"

Comment: WOW! That is the point! I just noticed the important small space before I came back and look at your answer. This is absolutely a "bug"  I think

Comment: But it works on my system without (): ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ogQWX.png)  no errors.

Comment: @Nasser the small space is the key. between "," and "input".  (,"input") will be wrong, (, "input") will be right

Comment: @matheorem, Ok, no space now between ">>" and `FileNameJoin`, still no error: ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WzPjt.png) I am not getting it. I do not know which space that is. I removed all the spaces and it still works for me. V 9.02, windows 7, 64 bit. but not important, as long as it works for you :)

Comment: @Nasser not that space. I mean the space here, see closely http://imgur.com/VHaiFDt. Can you notice that **one of the "input" is grey and the other is black**? If you type your code successively, the space is automatically preserved by mathematica syntax system. But I found if you use copy and paste the "Directory[]", the space strangely gone and that makes it wrong. So that is why I call it bug.

Comment: Reminds me of [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30489/infix-form-of-putappend-does-not-work-with-variable?rq=1)

Comment: @belisarius @cormullion I have tested many times and found that in the front end mode once the small space is preserved correctly, then `aaa >> FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]` or `aaa >> (FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "input"}])` both works. But when I run it in command line mode, `aaa >> FileNameJoin[{Directory[],"input"}]` will give a file named "FileNameJoin[...]". But `aaa >> (FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "input"}])`just give an error saying "Syntax::sntxf: "aaa" cannot be followed by ">>(FileNameJoin[{Directory[],lll}])""

Comment: @cormullion Yep. Probably the same issue