# How to use MakeExpression in terminal?

Tags: syntax, files-and-directories, output, user-interface

This is in continuation to the question in [Infix form of PutAppend ( >>> ) does not work with variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30489).

I was trying to use

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{lhs_, ">>>", rhs_String}], form_] :=
MakeExpression[
RowBox[{"PutAppend", "[", RowBox[{lhs, ",", rhs}], "]"}],
form
] /; ! StringMatchQ[rhs, "\"*\""]
```

In terminal, so that

```
out= "new"<>"file";
{5,5^2}>>>out
```

would send the expression into "newfile".
However the suggested solution failed.

How do I use `MakeExpression` in a terminal session?
Or otherwise use `>>>`
in terminal for a filename stored in an expression?

Comment: "How do I use MakeExpression in a terminal session?" <-- Things typed into a notebook are stored as [boxes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RepresentingTextualFormsByBoxes.html).  The conversion rules from boxes to expressions can be hacked (`MakeExpression`).  Things typed into a terminal are just text.  They're interpreted by the kernel's built-in parser, which cannot be changed or hacked.  Generally, stuff relying on boxes will only work in notebooks and requires a front end.  An example is the Notations package, which is not usable from the terminal.

Comment: You might want to try [`UsingFrontEnd`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UsingFrontEnd.html).

Answer (score 1):

To use `Put` or `PutAppend` with a filename saved in a string in terminal, one can use it in input form rather then `>>` or `>>>`, that is:

```
filename="newfile.txt"
Put[expression,filename]
```

or

```
PutAppend[expression,filename]
```

I found the answer in 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853676
by Brett Champion.

While this solves my problem, I would still like to be enlightened as to how to use MakeExpression in a terminal.

Cheers.