# Confused about scoping, not sure what to ask

Tags: scoping

I'm grading for a class using Mathematica right now, and one of the students ran into a weird issue.  When he ran code like this:

```
examplefun[n_] :=
    SetDirectory["/Users/"];
    Module[{output = ""},
    Do[output = output <> RandomInteger[{1, 4}], {i, n}];
    Print[output]]
```

He get's an error:
Do::iterb: "Iterator {i,n} does not have appropriate bounds. "

But if he moves Module up:

```
examplefun[n_] :=
    Module[{output = ""},
    SetDirectory["/Users/"];
    Do[output = output <> RandomInteger[{1, 4}], {i, n}];
    Print[output]]
```

The error disappears.  I'm not sure what the problem is, though I suspect it has something to do with scoping.  Could someone provide me with some insight here?

Thanks!

Edit:
Ohhhhhhhh, that makes sense!  Thanks for the prompt responses, everyone!  I hadn't considered that his code didn't use the proper syntax for a multi-line function since I haven't used multi-line syntax before.  I've accepted an answer, but thanks for all the responses!

Comment: Multi-line functions should be encapsulated with parenthesis. In the first version, `Module` is not part of the function but is executed on its own. So n is not defined.

Comment: I think you would benefit from reading these: [(3146)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121), [(30430)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a [precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) issue. [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) has a higher precedence than [`CompoundExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CompoundExpression.html) (`;`), so the first form does not include the `Module` in the definition at all.  This is why the iterator in `Do` does not have the appropriate bounds, `n` is defined only in the function.

Personally, I would use white-space in the function, to highlight where the scope boundaries are

```
examplefun[n_] :=
 Module[{output = ""},
  SetDirectory["/Users/"];
  Do[output = output <> RandomInteger[{1, 4}], {i, n}];
  Print[output]
 ]
```

This will not help with the first form, but it makes the second much easier to read.

Answer (score 5):

+1 to rcollyer for an excellent answer. But it's also good to know that parenthesis will fix the precedence issue:

```
examplefun[n_] := (
  SetDirectory["/Users/"];
  Module[
   {output = ""},
   Do[output = output <> ToString[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {i, n}];
   Print[output]
   ]
  )
```

And it's good to know how to figure out precedence issues using `FullForm` and `Hold`.

```
Hold[examplefun[n_] := (
    SetDirectory["/Users/"];
    Module[
     {output = ""},
     Do[output = output <> ToString[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {i, n}];
     Print[output]
     ]
    )] // FullForm
```

> `Hold[SetDelayed[examplefun[Pattern[n,Blank[]]],CompoundExpression[SetDirectory["/Users/"],Module[List[Set[output,""]],CompoundExpression[Do[Set[output,StringJoin[output,ToString[RandomInteger[List[1,4]]]]],List[i,n]],Print[output]]]]]]`

And

```
Hold[examplefun[n_] :=
   SetDirectory["/Users/"];
  Module[
   {output = ""},
   Do[output = output <> ToString[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {i, n}];
   Print[output]
   ]
  ] // FullForm
```

> `Hold[CompoundExpression[SetDelayed[examplefun[Pattern[n,Blank[]]],SetDirectory["/Users/"]],Module[List[Set[output,""]],CompoundExpression[Do[Set[output,StringJoin[output,ToString[RandomInteger[List[1,4]]]]],List[i,n]],Print[output]]]]]`

In *Mathematica*, so called standard-evaluation is to evaluate from the inside and out. This applies here, so we can see that in the first case `CompoundExpression` get evaluated before `SetDelayed` because it appears inside it. But in the second version `SetDelayed` is separated from the `Module` code, we clearly see that `n` is not available to `Do` but just looking at this. You could also use `TreeForm` on this expression to see that the different parts belong to different "branches."