# Associativity of `/@`

Tags: evaluation, syntax, operators

Why are the following not equivalent:

```
Map[Line, Map[(Print[#]; #) &, {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}]]
```

which produces

```
{{2,1},{1,1}}
{{-2,1},{3,1}}
{Line[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}]}
```

and:

```
Line /@ (Print[#]; #) & /@ {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}
```

which produces

```
{{2,1},{1,1}}
{{-2,1},{3,1}}
{{Line[{2, 1}], Line[{1, 1}]}, {Line[{-2, 1}], Line[{3, 1}]}}
```

Comment: Does the Documentation Center page `tutorial/OperatorInputForms`, with its listing in order of precedence, help?

Comment: Related: [(3143)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3143/121), [(30425)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The behaviour we see is due to the precedence of `&`, which is much lower than the precedence of `/@`.  As a consequence, the expression `Line /@ (Print[#]; #)` is bound tightly together by the high precedence `/@` infix operator, yielding the single argument to the low precedence `&` postfix operator.  This means that the second expression is interpreted as (note the added parentheses prior to the second `/@`):

```
(Line /@ (Print[#]; #) &) /@ {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
Map[Line /@ (Print[#]; #) &, {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}]
```

or

```
Map[Map[Line, (Print[#]; #) &], {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}]
```

This is manifestly different from the first expression in the question.

One way to see this in the front-end is to place the cursor somewhere within `Print` and then extend the selection using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> repeatedly.  With each key press, the selection grows outward to show how subexpressions group together due to precedence.  Repeatedly double-, triple-, quadruple-clicking, etc. on a selection point will also extend the selection to show precedence.

Another way to see how the expression is interpreted is to inspect its full-form:

```
Line /@ (Print[#];#)& /@ {{{2,1},{1,1}},{{-2,1},{3,1}}} // FullForm // HoldForm

(*
  Map[
    Function[Map[Line, CompoundExpression[Print[Slot[1]],Slot[1]]]],
    List[List[List[2,1],List[1,1]],List[List[-2,1],List[3,1]]]]
*)
```

The Wolfram Language documentation has a section that details [operator precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).

Comment: +1 for control-dot.  I didn't know about that until now!  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

```
Map[Line, Map[(Print[#]; #) &, {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}]]
```

is equivalent to

```
Line /@ ((Print[#]; #) & /@ {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}})
```

with both producing

```
{{2,1},{1,1}}
{{-2,1},{3,1}}
{Line[{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}], Line[{{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}]}
```

Note the extra pair of parentheses that I added.  They are necessary so that `Line` in the expression using `/@` is mapped to all of `((Print[#]; #) & /@ {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}})`, as it is in the expression using `Map` explicitly.

Comment: Okay, but how is `Line` mapped without the parentheses? Are the two not supposed to be equivalent? How is the result produced in the case of `Line /@ (Print[#]; #) & /@ {{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{-2, 1}, {3, 1}}}`? I would really appreciate an explanation.

Comment: Run Trace on the three expressions to see the differences.