# Nested mapping of a function

Tags: programming, function-construction

If I use the construct

```
f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

my function works, but if I use

```
Nest[f, #, 3] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

it doesn't. What is the difference, and how can I code the top example without copying and pasting?

Comment: Both give the same result in Version 9.0.1.0 (Windows 8 x64).

Comment: Have you tried both versions on a fresh (new) Mathematica session?

Comment: They are not the same if you define something for `f`.  Try it with, say, `f = #+1&`.

Comment: as wxffles says, there is a slight difference in nesting. It can be simulated by adding parentheses.

Comment: Are you certain that you want a neat version of the first construct? Honest question

Comment: f@*f@*f /@ {a, b, c} or f@f@f[#] & /@ {a, b, c}

Comment: @Rojo I say yes with trepedation ... I am guessing it is rather complicated ...

Comment: @Algohi how do I do that without copying & pasting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Analysis

[`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html) is left-associative as [converting to StandardForm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) reveals:

```
(((f[#1] &) /@ f[#1] &) /@ f[#1] &) /@ {a, b, c}
```

You can see the result of the rather odd operation with:

```
f = {#, "x"} &;

f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {{{{a, x}, {x, x}}, {{x, x}, {x, x}}},
>  {{{b, x}, {x, x}}, {{x, x}, {x, x}}},
>  {{{c, x}, {x, x}}, {{x, x}, {x, x}}}}
> ```

(Obviously the structure is specific to the output of `f` but I hope it serves to illustrate.)

Additionally the order of evaluation is not the same as a [`Map` operation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46238/121) with a *levelspec* because one entire branch executes first.  Compare these results:

```
i = 0;
f = {#, i++} &;
f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

> ```
> {{{{a, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{0, 5}, {4, 6}}},
>  {{{b, 9}, {8, 10}}, {{7, 12}, {11, 13}}},
>  {{{c, 16}, {15, 17}}, {{14, 19}, {18, 20}}}}
> ```

```
i = 0;
f = {#, i++} &;
Fold[Map[f, #, {#2}] &, {a, b, c}, Range@3]
```

> ```
> {{{{a, 9}, {3, 10}}, {{0, 11}, {4, 12}}},
>  {{{b, 13}, {5, 14}}, {{1, 15}, {6, 16}}},
>  {{{c, 17}, {7, 18}}, {{2, 19}, {8, 20}}}}
> ```

I am attempting to think of a *clean* way to produce the first output (with arbitrary levels of mapping).

### Solution

After a [chat session](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21033/discussion-between-mr-wizard-and-martin) I propose:

```
mapRepeated[f_, expr_, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  Nest[x \[Function] x /@ f[#] &, f, n - 1] /@ expr
```

Test:

```
i = 0;

mapRepeated[{#, i++} &, {a, b, c}, 3]
```

> ```
> {{{{a, 2}, {1, 3}}, {{0, 5}, {4, 6}}},
>  {{{b, 9}, {8, 10}}, {{7, 12}, {11, 13}}},
>  {{{c, 16}, {15, 17}}, {{14, 19}, {18, 20}}}}
> ```

Using *Mathematica 10* syntax the we can simplify `mapRepeated` slightly:

```
mapRepeated[f_, expr_, n_Integer?Positive] :=
  Nest[Map[#]@*f &, f, n - 1] /@ expr
```

Comment: Your are faster ;) so you can add that this fact may be surprising because: `f /@ f /@ f /@ {a}` works differently.

Comment: @Kuba Correct, `Map` is right-associative.

Comment: @martin If your first way is ok but second gives wrong result I'd think that the problem is in `f`. The question is, do you want to repeatively map `f` over a `set`? Well, you are not doing this with your first solution. (*but maybe I've missed something*)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, just found out that the order is important - sorry! :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21033/discussion-between-mr-wizard-and-martin).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which from of the solutions you are looking at but you can try this:

```
f = #+1&; 
Composition[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[f, 2]][f[#]] & /@ {a, b, c}
(*{3 + a, 3 + b, 3 + c}*)
```

how about this:

```
Nest[Map[f, #,{-1}] &, f[#], 2] & /@ {a, b, c}
```

Comment: Not working with my function I'm afraid -  sorry to be a pain!

Comment: Not working at all or gives different result than you expected?

Comment: I think it must be my strangely constructed initial function.

Comment: It works well on the example you gave, but my function doesn't like it.

Comment: @Algori I'm afraid not - the first gies the same output as `Nest[f, #, 3] & /@ {a, b, c}`, the second gives a different output, but not the desired one.

Comment: I get confused. which results you are looking for in your question. is it the result from f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ {a, b, c} or from Nest[f, #, 3] & /@ {a, b, c}?

Comment: unfortunately, that doesn't work wither. BTW it is the first of your 2 examples that I am after - `f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ f[#] & /@ {a, b, c}`

Comment: Hmmm, I give up :)