# f /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ matrix

Tags: syntax

How can one write `f /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ # & /@ matrix` in one line with arbitrary level and without using `Map` functions level argument or assigning to any variable names?

Comment: What is the reason for this exercise? With `Map[f, matrix, {5}]` you can achieve exactly the same but in more concise and efficient way: `matrix = Array[i, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]; Map[f, matrix, {5}] == Nest[Function[{x}, Map[#, x]] &, f, 5][matrix]` returns `True`.

Comment: Purely recreational. I wanted to write it using recursion (nesting), but it took me a while to understand what kind of recursion was happening. Here the function uses itself to create a new function that itself returns. Nice to see how this behavior can be expressed concisely. You can't do it with using just the #& syntax. You have to use the Function function as well.

Comment: Closely related: [Nested mapping of a function (73762)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73762/121)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the spirit of recreation, I offer the following unlikely but effective expression which uses only pure functions:

```
Nest[{Function @@ Hold[# /@ #2], #2} & @@ # &, {f, #}, 5][[1]][matrix]
```

The need to introduce named variables is avoided by means of "bare slots", i.e. the use of `#` outside of `Function` forms.  This is a hazardous practice infrequently used in "real" code, but this is for fun, right?

A shorter, but still cryptic, solution uses "disguised slots" instead of "bare slots":

```
Nest[#[#2 /@ #3]&[Function, #, Slot@@{1}] &, f, 5][matrix]
```

The action of the second form is easier to visualize than the first:

```
lift = #[#2 /@ #3] &[Function, #, Slot @@ {1}] &

Nest[lift, f, 5]
(* ((((f /@ #1 &) /@ #1 &) /@ #1 &) /@ #1 &) /@ #1 & *)
```

Version 10 introduced an operator form for `Map`, so the preceding ugly expressions can be simplified to the much more manageable:

```
Nest[Map, f, 5][matrix]
```

which is almost as succinct as the expression `Map[f, matrix, {5}]` banned by the question.

Answer (score 5):

From the expression it might be hard to see what is happening. Lets reformat it like this.
 `(((((((f /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ # &) /@ matrix`
What is happening is, there is a function f that is given as an argument to a function that returns a new function that maps f to its argument. You can write this as a pure function like this `Function[{x}, Map[#, x]] &`. This can be Nested arbitrary times.
`Nest[Function[{x}, Map[#, x]] &, f, 5][matrix]`