# Grouping/precedence for "/@" operator

Tags: function-construction, syntax

This returns errors:

```
{#[[1]],#[[3]]} & /@ {#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]} & /@ {{"A","B","C"},{1,2,3}}
```

> Part::partd: Part specification A[[1]] is longer than depth of object. >>
>   ...

But when adding parentheses after first `/@` (`Map`) and closing it on the end of expression, as in:

```
{#[[1]],#[[3]]} & /@ ({#[[1]],#[[2]],#[[3]]} & /@ {{"A","B","C"},{1,2,3}})
```

everything goes fine and returns expected result: `{{"A", "C"}, {1, 3}}`

How to explain the behavior of first case? I cannot figure out what cause errors in first case.

Comment: Your question notwithstanding, are you perhaps looking for `{{"A", "B", "C"}, {1, 2, 3}}[[All, {1, 3}]]`? You might also be interested in [Elegant operations on matrix rows and columns](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3069/27951).

Comment: No. I ask, why first case returns errors: `"Part specification \!\(\"A\"[[1]]\) is longer than depth of object."`, and returns something like generic result `{{{"A"[[1]], "A"[[3]]}, {"B"[[1]], "B"[[3]]}, {"C"[[1]], 
   "C"[[3]]}}, {{1[[1]], 1[[3]]}, {2[[1]], 2[[3]]}, {3[[1]], 3[[3]]}}}`
Expected result should be as in 2nd case.

Comment: Perhaps you could point out explicitly why you think that the behavior you observed is not in accordance with operator precedence rules (see e.g. [Operator Input Forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) and [this answer]).(http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/27951).

Comment: Tank you. I figured out the point I missed. This was the the way the `Map` function works on it's arguments.

Comment: Related: [(73762)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/73762/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this example helps:

```
3 # & /@ Sin[#] & /@ {x, y, z}
(*{Sin[3 x], Sin[3 y], Sin[3 z]}*)
```

vs.

```
3 # & /@ (Sin[#] & /@ {x, y, z})
(*{3 Sin[x], 3 Sin[y], 3 Sin[z]}*)
```

Comment: OK. this is useful as a starting point for me. But:
`Trace[3#& /@ Sin[#] &@x]` produces `{((3#1&)/@Sin[#1]&)[x], (3#1&), /@ Sin[x], Sin[(3#1&)[x]], {(3#1&)[x], 3x}Sin[3x]}`. And I don't understan how 3rd step isproduced, because `Map[f, expr]` is equvalent of `f /@ expr`, so 3rd step should be `3 [Sin[x]]`.
Where is the point I miss?

Comment: @Dragutin Doesn't PrecedenceForm make it clear what is happening?

Comment: Yes. Tank you.
Now everything is clear. I missunderstood functioning of `Map` function.

Answer (score 6):

To understand grouping and precedence, use `HoldForm` and `PrecedenceForm`.  I'll insert a screenshot to make the output clearer:

[image]

It is useful to know that `//` has even lower precedence than `&` and can save you some parentheses.

You probably meant:

```
({#[[1]], #[[3]]} &) /@ ({#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &) /@ {{"A", "B", "C"}, {1, 2, 3}}
```

It is useful to parenthesize the entire function because `&` has very low precedence, lower than most other operators.  Thus it tends to act on *everything* preceding it.

---

Another common mistake with `&` is using it like this in options:

```
SomeFunction -> #&
```

This is really `(SomeFunction -> #)&` and not `SomeFunction -> (#&)`.

---

One of the few operators that have even lower precedence than `&` is `//`.  Thus this is safe:

```
argument // #&
```

It groups as `argument // (#&)` and not as `(argument // #)&`.

---

Alternative ways to write you expression are:

```
Map[{#[[1]], #[[3]]} &] @ Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &] @ {{"A", "B", "C"}, {1, 2, 3}}

{{"A", "B", "C"}, {1, 2, 3}} // Map[{#[[1]], #[[2]], #[[3]]} &] // Map[{#[[1]], #[[3]]} &]
```

You may or may not find these more readable than the explicitly parenthesized version.

Recently I prefer the latter when doing a lot of chaining.