# Use of parenthesis and pure function

Tags: pure-function

I had read that when using a pure-function it was a good general practice to enclose the function and the associated ampersand in parenthesis.

```
(#^2 &)[a]
```

I have found this to work fine and adopted the practice.

Then I found it would not work with this example:

```
 {Animator[Dynamic[x, (x = Round[#, 0.001] &)]], Dynamic[x]}
```

When you click Run, nothing happens.

For this specific example I have to place the ampersand after the parenthesis in order for it to work.

```
{Animator[Dynamic[x, (x = Round[#, 0.001]) &]], Dynamic[x]}
```

I would appreciate it if this behavior could be explained.

Comment: Try: `Hold[x = # &] // FullForm` and `Hold[(x = #) &] // FullForm`. You need the whole assignment to be a function when in first example `&` binds with *rhs* faster than `Set`. Looking for duplicate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe:

In:

```
Clear[x]
(x = Round[#, 0.001] &);
Definition[x]
```

Out:

```
"x = Round[#1, 0.001] &"
```

this means you assigned the fure punction to be the definition of x.

Now observe how the correct syntax works:

In:

```
Clear[x]
(x = Round[#, 0.001]) &;
Definition[x]
```

Out:

```
"Null"
```

now x has not been defined, because `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll`.

In general use this notation if you want to be sure:

```
((body)&)[args]
```

in your case you would use inner parenthesis to define the body of the function and outer parenthesis to seperate the purefunction from other code

In:

```
((x = Round[#, 0.001]) &)[Pi]
```

Out:

```
3.142
```

**EDIT:**

A deeper explanation why this happens is that `Function` (&) has a lower precedence than `Set` ("="). See also these two informative answers:

[`f[g]` not the same as `f@g`?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg)

[check precedences](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3143/using-a-list-of-tuples-in-a-pure-function/3146#3146)